# Changing the look and feel of the project to Dark Metal in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded some plugins for NetBeans 8.x:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40985/ez-on-da-ice
and
*Dark Look and Feel Themes* available from the plugin menu in NetBeans.
I wanted to use Dark Metal theme as look and feel for my project, not for NetBeans and I can't find a way to do it.

It is even possible? If right-click on the frame in the design view I can choose "Preview Design -> Dark Metal | Ez Charcoal" but I can't find these themes to set them as Look and feel through `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`.

Answer (score 1):

The plugins you downloaded are in deed for Netbeans itself. If you are developing a Swing application yoy need to make different look and feels available on the classpath of your application.
You can try the web look and feel, which is available here: https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf
It comes with an example and installation guide.